# How to display custom data on mouseover of column chart in highchart in addition to series data?

Tags: highcharts

I am using below highchart to display monthly avarage sells,

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

How do I display list of 10 top selling products with their sell amount on mouseover of the column chart?

This is how my series is,

series: [{"name":"Buys","type":"column","color":"#4572A7","yAxis":1,"data":[0,0,0,126,410605,0,0,0,0,0,0,103412]}]

Also

How can I add additional data in case of bubble chart as the data array is like data : [[12, 43, 13], [74, 23, 44]] . what are the keys for the data values ? Are there 'x', 'y' and 'z' ? or 'size' ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [High charts showing the composition of count as tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578122/high-charts-showing-the-composition-of-count-as-tooltip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the data as below

```
    series:[{
     data: [{
      x: timestamp,
      y: value,
      passCount: someVlaue,
      totalCount: someValue
     }]
    }]
```

and access it from tooltip

```
tooltip:{
 formatter: function() {
  this.point.options.passCount
  this.point.options.total
 }
}
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Mn6sB/9.

Comment: How can I add additional data in case of bubble chart as the data array is like data : [[12, 43, 13], [74, 23, 44]] . what are the keys for the data values ? Are there 'x', 'y' and 'z' ? or 'size' ?

Comment: Yes, in bubble use `{ x: X, y: Y, z: Z }`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [tooltip](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.tooltip) config. There's a sample in the document (pointFormat).

You can also use a function to fully control what you want to render on tooltip. The document is [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter), with samples.

Comment: Thanks, but variables seems to be limited e.g.  point.x, point.y, series.name and series.color etc but I want to display custom data for each column which are not series values.

Comment: You can: 1.put extra fields into your data and access them in the function body like "this", or "this.point", or 2. use a global object if they share a common data like "total", "average". It's just a javascript function which runs when mouse over, you can put closure into it.